# populate a new field based on the first portion of an existing field

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update

I am working on a database project and one of the tasks is to populate a newly created field 'institution' with the first portion of the field course_id which is HarvardX/CB22x/2013_Spring. So I need to populate the institution field with the first portion only 'HarvardX. How can I do that in MySQL workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring_index()`:

```
update mytable
set institution = substring_index(course_id, '/', 1)
```

If you want to also extract the middlde part and end part, then:

```
update mytable
set 
    institution = substring_index(course_id, '/', 1),
    other_col   = substring_index(substring(course_id, locate('/', course_id) + 1), '/', 1),
    more_col    = substring_index(course_id, '/', -1)
```

Comment: I got the following error message 'error code 1193 unknow system variable 'institution'

Comment: @AmandaRamos: your question mentions a column named `institution`, don't you have such column in your table?

Comment: it works now, I forgot to add update mytable :) if I want to update another field with the second portion of HarvardX/CB22x/2013_Spring to be CB22x and the third 2013_Spring what is the location?

Comment: @AmandaRamos: you should have asked that from the start... Nevertheless, see my update.